# POSTGRESQL Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, rubygems

Ok i got this problem when i try to create a new rails project,
But first i will show you that i have setting up the usual problems ( Ruby version, bundler, brew postgresql

```
~
▶ type rbenv
rbenv is a shell function

▶ gem list | grep bundler
bundler (1.10.6)

▶ rbenv local
rbenv: no local version configured for this directory

▶ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql

▶ which bundler
/Users/hectorleon/.rbenv/shims/bundler

▶ which postgresql
postgresql not found

▶ which psql     
/usr/local/bin/psql
▶ brew list
autoconf    git     mpfr      openssl     python      readline    xz
boost     gmp     mysql     pcre      python3     redis     zsh
gcc     isl     node      pkg-config    rbenv     ruby-build    zsh-completions
gdbm      libmpc      numpy     postgresql    rbenv-gem-rehash  sqlite

▶ createuser myusername
createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "myusername" already exists

▶ brew install postgresql
Warning: postgresql-9.4.5_2 already installed

▶ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]

▶ gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.4
Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.4
Done installing documentation for pg after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

▶ brew list
autoconf    git     libpqxx     numpy     postgresql    rbenv-gem-rehash  sqlite
boost     gmp     mpfr      openssl     python      readline    xz
gcc     isl     mysql     pcre      python3     redis     zsh
gdbm      libmpc      node      pkg-config    rbenv     ruby-build    zsh-completions
```

Ok, a bunch of stuff installed using Homebrew and rbenv. Now lets create a rails project a see what happen.

```
▶ rails new whygodwhy -d postgresql
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password: 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.7
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.5
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.5
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.5
Using mime-types 2.99
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.5
Using activemodel 4.2.5
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.5
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bundler 1.10.6
Using byebug 8.2.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.5
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.2
Using jquery-rails 4.0.5
Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  --with-pg
  --without-pg
  --enable-windows-cross
  --disable-windows-cross
  --with-pg-config
  --without-pg-config
  --with-pg_config
  --without-pg_config
  --with-pg-dir
  --without-pg-dir
  --with-pg-include
  --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
  --with-pg-lib
  --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
  --with-pqlib
  --without-pqlib
  --with-libpqlib
  --without-libpqlib
  --with-ms/libpqlib
  --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/m0/v30d40yd31bc5hf1lqrt5zn00000gn/T/bundler20151205-52465-pssww8pg-0.18.4/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/m0/v30d40yd31bc5hf1lqrt5zn00000gn/T/bundler20151205-52465-pssww8pg-0.18.4/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:347:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:325:in `each'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:325:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:198:in `start'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:182:in `resolve'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `resolve'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

OK... so i see that say "Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)"
How can installing it ? no idea, and found nothing in Google.

In addition if i try to inside postgresql folder i got this message

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file. You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable
```

Summarizing:

- I installed successfully pg gem (native extension created successfully) but after, the rails project says that i cannot build native extension.
- Says i need password to install gems when i have the bundler installed and the rbenv nice :S no sense
- I haven't the libpq and i didn't know how/where or what command i need :S
- And i have postgresql installed but not a server configuration file
- I gonna die haha, no seriously someone can help me ? i wasted like 5 hours in two days trying to fix this, the laptop is new and have OSX EL Capitán installed.

Comment: This looks like you're picking up a version of rails installed using the system ruby

Comment: Try running the suggestion of the error message and resolve possible dependencies: gem install pg -v '0.18.4'. As I read the msg, it looks like you are missing rails itself??

Comment: @FrederickCheung how can i check what ruby is taken ? :S

Comment: @benjamin both command return me 
Could not locate Gemfile
But the gemfile are in projects already created, so i don't understand

Comment: `which rails` would show you where the rails install is coming from

Comment: @FrederickCheung 
▶ which rails
/usr/bin/rails

▶ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]

Comment: That's exactly the issue then - you are picking up a rails install associated with the system ruby because you haven't installed the rails gem with your rbenv provided ruby

Comment: Héctor, @FrederickCheung, running the command "rails --version" shows the version you are using.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/296873/install-libpq-dev-on-mac-os could give you the other dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)

You are missing the library named *libpq*. After installing it, see how the error message changes and repeat the process, if necessary.

It could be that this library goes by a slightly different name, like *libpq5*, so if you do not find a 100% match, you might wanna give these a try.

Comment: I have 2 problems:

1) i need libpq ( don't know where or how install it  :S )

2) postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.

Comment: People on SO are more willing to help, if they see some research effort on the side of the questioner. I would kindly refer you to the first results of a GOOGLE search, with the same keywords as the title of your question. Whether you solve your issue or not by doing so, you might want to update your original post.

Comment: i saw similar question but not exactly the same, i got ruby setup, i got rbenv, i had postgresql install using brew and gem pg installed also (these were the usuall problems to solve in the other SO topics), but i still have this issue, so i thought that in my case its other problem :S @benjamin

Comment: Héctor, how are you getting along?

Comment: still fail, so i gonna remove this afternoon everything about postgreSQL and try reinstall again, 
because y create a new project with mysql and everything works.